# C malloc doesn't work the way I expected it to

Tags: c, ubuntu, malloc

I have no idea what is wrong this code.

```
char *names;
int i = 6;
names = (char *) malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));

printf("%d", strlen(names));
```

0 is the result instead of 7, but why?

//I learnt using malloc like this: tomb = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));

Comment: `malloc` does not initialize allocated memory, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: You're unlucky that the `malloc()` you're using handed out zeroed memory; many versions would not and you might as easily have gotten an answer in the hundreds as 0.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski `i+1` bytes are allocated.

Comment: Note that `strlen()` does not count (terminating) null character. As you have `i+1=7` bytes allocated, the maximum value is 6 (i.e. the same as `i`'s value). This of course is independent issue of reading indeterminate values, as described comprehensively in Zack's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line by line...

```
int len1 = 0;
int i = 6;
```

These should both be `size_t`.

```
names = (char *) malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
```

You did not show the variable declaration for `names`.  I am going to assume it is `char *`, but in the future make sure to show the variable declarations for *all* variables, or even better, provide a *complete* test program that we can compile and run for ourselves if we have to.

In C, do not cast the return value of `malloc`.  In all C-family languages, do not write `sizeof(char)`, it is 1 *by definition*.

You need to check whether `malloc` failed (returned `NULL`).

```
while (names[len1] != '\0')
```

Undefined behavior on this line, because the memory returned from `malloc` is uninitialized.  The loop may iterate *any number* of times, including zero, seven, six, five, four, three, two, one, eight, nine, ten, 4096, and infinity.  It is also entitled to crash the program or even make demons fly out of your nose.

```
    len1++;
```

Also, you have reinvented `strlen`.

```
printf("%d", len1);
```

Need a `\n` after the `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Zack what he says is good for you. Be mindful to read about strcpy and malloc they always caused me problems when I first started.

This works...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int len1 = 0;
    int i = 6;
    char *names = malloc(i + 1);

    strcpy(names, "hi");
    while (names[len1] != '\0')
        len1++;

    printf("%d\n", len1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `strcpy(names,"hi\0");` is curious.  Reccomend simply `strcpy(names,"hi");` 2) Simplify `names = (char *) malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));` to `names = malloc(i+1);` or `names = malloc((i+1) * sizeof *name);`.